# Coffee script compilation error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

This is my coffee, I simply can't see why this is wrong. I keep getting an unexpected , error.

```
renderTable:()=>
    @table = d3.select("#search-results-area").append("table").attr("id",@tableId).attr("class","visualization-panel")
    @thead = @table.append("thead")
    @tbody = @table.append("tbody")
    @input = @table.append("input").attr("id",@inputId).on("keydown",(d)=>
        console.log("keydown")
        console.log 
        toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 
        window.setTimeout(()=> 
            toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 
            @tbody.selectAll("tr")
        ,500)
    )
```

When I take out the `@tbody.selectAll("tr")`, this works, which is what's confusing me.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it has to do with the way you are defining your `window.setTimeout` section. The `,500)` piece at the end is causing the compile error because of indentation and the parenthesis. Try changing that section to:

```
window.setTimeout ( ->
    toFilter = $(@input[0][0]).val() 
    @tbody.selectAll("tr")
), 500
```

Keep the closing paren indented to the same spot as `window`. That should fix the compile.